# Layer over zxing scanner

Tags: android, barcode, layer, qr-code, zxing

I'm writing an App for Android which uses the ZXing scanner. I'd like to place a layer over this activity to show some customized messages or images while the user is scanning.
Is it possible? If so, how?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrated via the Barcode Scanner application, no.

If you put their source code in your app, then you can modify their activity to add in your layer.